# Keeping a consistent audio volume across multiple pages (HTML/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, volume

So essentially what I'm looking to do is have a volume slider that is available in the settings menu, and have that slider affect the volume of the music on all of the pages of my website. Is this possible, or is there perhaps another way to accomplish a similar thing?

Comment: How about letting the user determine volume using their browser's/OS's built in controls? What's changing across your pages that you need to be concerned about this?

Comment: Do you mean to update several open pages at once? Or regardless of the user's location on your website, it's pulling from the same volume setting?

Answer (score 0):

To maintain states across pages you can use session variables(stored on server) or cookies.

Also, as Bob pointed out, why not let user control the volume?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wanted to have separate controls for sfx, music, etc. which CANNOT be done by simply altering the volume of the browser. And, yes, the idea is to let the user control the individual volumes using the sliders.

Comment: @user2316502 are you making some kind of audio mixing DAW in browser?
Also, if this is the case, you can use cookies, or variables which are stored locally at the client, if you are using some king of frontend library and making a single page application, then this shouldn't be hard.

Comment: I'm making a kind of in browser game of sorts that currently runs across multiple pages unfortunately. I have a main landing page, along with a settings page, a page for each gamemode, and several other minor pages accessed from the landing page. Would there be perhaps a way to feed a variable into a page from the previous one via the onload function?